# grep with "from this to that" flipflop semantics?

Tags: perl, awk, grep

`grep` allows to see the context of a match by using the `-A`, `-B`, and `-C` options, e.g.

```
grep -B 3 -A 10 "WARNING" MyApp.log
```

`perl` one-liners allow easily extracting text, that is between a start and end line, each matching a different regexp, using the bistable flip-flip operator in the form

```
perl -ne '(/^WARNING/../^$/) && print' MyApp.log
```

but there is no obvious way to include context lines other than by writing a more complex script - definitely not an ad-hoc solution for quick use on the command line.

Is there some feature in `grep`/`perl` that I am missing, or some third tool, that allows combining both flip-flop semantics and context lines?

Comment: I don't think there is, no.

Comment: Seems like you are asking for a rather complex behavior (I am not sure exactly what you want) and so it's likely calling for a program, not a ready capability.  It could be rather compact, given Perl's abilities for that, but I can't imagine anything providing that as a single call or operator.

Comment: You just want to print every line in blocks starting with WARNING to the next empty line? `sed -n '/^WARNING/,/^$/p' MyApp.log` is a bit simpler than your perl version.

Comment: With the mandatory POSIX toolset: `grep` is the best tool for doing `g/re/p`, `sed` is the best tool for doing `s/old/new/` and for anything else you'd use `awk`. If you [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can show you how to do whatever it is you're trying to do. Make sure to tell us if you need string or regexp matching, full line, full word, or partial matching, and include overlapping and nested and incomplete ranges in your sample input/output so you don't end up getting answers to some other problem than you actually have.

Comment: Also tell us how large your input file typically is (so we get an idea if a solution that reads the whole input into memory is reasonable or not) and whether or not you have GNU tools.

Comment: @EdMorton GNU tools can be assumed, since it is a desktop Linux environment in practice. The files can be way too large for loading them into memory, though in most cases they remain small enough. Judging from the answers posted so far, it does look like there are no one-liner solutions to the task though.

Comment: There is a one-liner posted but it's using `ed` which does read the whole file into memory first so YMMV. Asking for a one-liner usually discourages answers as it means you favor brevity over everything that really matters (clarity, robustness, efficiency, portability, etc.). You also haven't seen many solutions yet because you haven't provided sample input/output, nor told is is you need regex vs string matching, partial vs full, nor how to handle overlapping ranges, etc. as discussed in my previous comment. We can't post a solution if we don't know what your requirements are.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question right, you want to print out blocks starting N lines before a line that matches a regular expression, and on to the next blank line and M lines after it?

This is actually really simple to do with good old `ed`:

```sh
$ cat foo.log
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
WARNING LINE
line 5
line 6

line 7
line 8
line 9
line 10
line 11
WARNING LINE
line 12

line 13
line 14
$ printf '%s\n' 'g/^WARNING/-3,/^$/+1p' | ed -s foo.log
line 2
line 3
line 4
WARNING LINE
line 5
line 6

line 7
line 9
line 10
line 11
WARNING LINE
line 12

line 13
```

As you can see, this particular invocation prints out the 3 lines prior to each WARNING up to the line after the next blank line. It's not a good solution for very large files, though, because `ed` loads the whole file. If that's the case you need something that keeps a rolling window of lines. Here's a `perl` example that tracks context:

```sh
perl -ne 'push @lines, $_;
          if (/^WARNING/../^$/) { $in_warn = 1 }
          shift @lines if !$in_warn && @lines > 3;
          if ($in_warn && /^$/) { $end_line = $. + 1 }
          if ($end_line == $.) { print @lines; @lines=(); $in_warn = 0 }' foo.log
```

Comment: `print @lines; @lines=();` -> `print splice(@lines)` :)

Answer (score 2):

Alternate implementation:

```sh
perl -sne'
   push @buf, $_;
   $in_warn ||= /^WARNING/;
   print splice(@buf) if $in_warn || $to_print-- > 0;
   shift(@buf) if @buf > $B;
   if ($in_warn && /^$/) { $in_warn = 0; $to_print = $A; }
' -- -B=3 -A=3
```

This one keeps at most B+1 lines in memory. It also uses `-s` to allow the size of the context to be specified using arguments.